# Why does cron not mail me the job output?

Tags: email, postfix, cron

Here's my crontab:

```
MAILTO=michael
02 11 * * * bash /home/michael/projectname/nightly_tests.sh
* * * * * python /home/michael/projectname/throwaway/hello.py
```

My username is specified correctly:

-bash-4.1$ whoami
michael

Here's what I'm trying to run every minute:

```
-bash-4.1$ cat /home/michael/projectname/throwaway/hello.py
print "hello world"
```

My mail file is empty:

```
-bash-4.1$ ll /var/mail/michael 
-rw-rw---- 1 michael mail 0 Feb 19 23:04 /var/mail/michael
```

Why is no mail being sent?  What can I do to fix this?

I'm on CentOS (3.7.5-linode48).

**EDIT** The maillog says this:

```
-bash-4.1$ sudo tail /var/log/maillog
Apr 13 11:49:01 servername postfix/sendmail[6989]: warning: the Postfix sendmail command must be installed without set-uid root file permissions
Apr 13 11:50:01 servername postfix/sendmail[6996]: warning: the Postfix sendmail command has set-uid root file permissions
Apr 14 11:50:01 servername postfix/sendmail[6996]: warning: or the command is run from a set-uid root process
Apr 13 11:50:01 servername postfix/sendmail[6996]: warning: the Postfix sendmail command must be installed without set-uid root file permissions
Apr 13 11:51:01 servername postfix/sendmail[7003]: warning: the Postfix sendmail command has set-uid root file permissions
Apr 13 11:51:01 servername postfix/sendmail[7003]: warning: or the command is run from a set-uid root process
Apr 13 11:51:01 servername postfix/sendmail[7003]: warning: the Postfix sendmail command must be installed without set-uid root file permissions
Apr 13 11:52:01 servername postfix/sendmail[7008]: warning: the Postfix sendmail command has set-uid root file permissions
Apr 13 11:52:01 servername postfix/sendmail[7008]: warning: or the command is run from a set-uid root process
Apr 13 11:52:01 servername postfix/sendmail[7008]: warning: the Postfix sendmail command must be installed without set-uid root file permissions
```

Going to go Google for what that means now.

Comment: What does your maillog say?

Comment: Ah, this is helpful.  Please have a look at my updated question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in CentOS with the combination of cron and postfix. See [this bug report](http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=5571). As far as I can see, there's no fix for it yet, but you could try installing an older version of cron and see if that helps matters.

Answer (score 0):

I got in touch with the admin of the server.  This is what he had to say:

> No, it's even more basic than that - the mailserver doesn't run by
>   default. I've turned it on and enabled it now, so you should get a ton
>   of email coming through that will have just been spooled.

**FACEPALM**